# Ripple Counter Using Dflip flop

Tags: counter, verilog

I wrote this code for simulating an asynchronous counter using D flip flop. The program gives correct output for the first to iterations but then the output doesn't change at all. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

***1st module:***

```
module DFF(d,q,reset,clk);
  input      d,reset,clk;
  output reg q;

  always @(posedge reset, posedge clk) begin
    if(reset) begin
      q=0;
    end
    if(d)
      q=d;
    else
      q=q;
   end
endmodule
```

***second module:***

```
module RippleCounter(d,clk,reset,out);
  input  [3:0] d;
  input        clk, reset;
  output [3:0] out; // 4bit

  DFF a(d[0],out[0],reset,clk);
  DFF b(d[1],out[1],reset,out[0]);
  DFF c(d[2],out[2],reset,out[1]);
  DFF dx(d[3],out[3],reset,out[2]);
endmodule
```

***3rd module:***

```
module RippleCounterTOP;
  reg  [3:0] d;
  reg        clk, reset;
  wire [3:0] out;

  RippleCounter r(d,clk,reset,out);

  initial begin
    d=0;clk=0;reset=1;
  end

  always begin 
    #5 d=d+1; clk=~clk;
  end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [this picture](http://www.eecs.tufts.edu/~dsculley/tutorial/flopsandcounters/flops6.html) of a ripple counter, the only input from your testharness should be the clock.

The type of flop used would typically look something like:

```
always @(posedge reset, posedge clk) begin
  if(reset) begin
    q <= 'b0;
  end
  else begin
    q <= ~q;
  end
end
```

In module 1 `always@(posedge clk ..` you should be using non-blocking `<=` assignments instead of `=`.

In module 3 you have an always block with out a sensitivity list, I would add the `@*`, This looks like you really want an initial with a repeat or a for loop to execute your test then call `$finish()` once complete. I have used `#5ns` SystemVerilog below but you could change to `#5` if required.

```
integer i;
initial begin 
  d=0;clk=0;reset=1;
  #5ns
  reset=0;

  for (i=0; i<5'b1000; i=i+1) begin
    #5ns d=d+1; clk=~clk;
    $display("%4b, %4b", d, out);
  end
  $finish;
end
```

Trying out your example, this is what I have ended up with I think it is what you were trying to do: NOTE the correct answer is `~out`.

**Module 1**, could be expanded with q and q_bar outputs.

```
module DFF(q,reset,clk);
  input      reset,clk;
  output reg q;

  always @(posedge reset, posedge clk) begin
    if(reset) begin
      q<=0;
    end
    else begin
      q<=~q;
   end
 end
endmodule
```

**Module 2**

```
module RippleCounter(clk,reset,out);
  input        clk, reset;
  output [3:0] out; // 4bit

  DFF ax(out[0],reset,clk);
  DFF bx(out[1],reset,out[0]);
  DFF cx(out[2],reset,out[1]);
  DFF dx(out[3],reset,out[2]);
endmodule
```

**Module 3** (Testharness)

```
module RippleCounterTOP;
  reg        clk, reset;
  wire [3:0] out;

  RippleCounter r(clk,reset,out);

  integer i;

  initial begin
    clk=0;reset=1;
    #5ns
    reset=0;

    for (i=0; i<6'b10000; i=i+1) begin
      #5ns clk=~clk;
      $display("%4b", ~out);
    end
    $finish;
  end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you expect your output to do, but one problem is that you are always resetting your DFFs.

Comment: I am reset the output bits for every new iteration that is after every 5 time units.